# Unable to set default value to timestamptz-type column in postgres while DB timezone setting is different than UTC

Tags: postgresql, timezone

## Table I want to create

Please, pay attention to default value of `ts` column. From `psql`:

```
root=# create temporary table test (
id int,
ts timestamptz not null default '0001-01-01 00:00:00 Z'
);
```

### Container without environment variable setting to change timezone

```
root=# show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)
```

Result of create table (**correct default**):

```
root=# \d+ test
                                                                       Table "pg_temp_3.test"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                       | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer                  |           |          |                                                    | plain   |             |              | 
 ts     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | '0001-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone | plain   |             |              | 
Access method: heap
```

> **Note**: This default value is the expected behaviour, but I need the container to be set to a different timezone in order to the `now()` function to work properly. The `now()` function is used as default value in another column.

### Container with correct timezone

Setting timezone with:

```
$ docker run --name postgres_test -p 5432:5432 -e "TZ=Brazil/East" -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password -d postgres:14-alpine
```

From `psql` (**correct timezone**):

```
root=# show timezone;
  TimeZone   
-------------
 Brazil/East
(1 row)
```

Selecting current time (**correct return**):

```
root=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2021-12-17 01:19:07.720302-03
(1 row)
```

But when I create the table I get back an **incorrect default** for column `ts`:

```
root=# \d+ test
                                                                           Table "pg_temp_3.test"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                           Default                           | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer                  |           |          |                                                             | plain   |             |              | 
 ts     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | '0001-12-31 20:53:32-03:06:28 BC'::timestamp with time zone | plain   |             |              | 
Access method: heap
```

The default value is set to `'0001-12-31 20:53:32-03:06:28 BC'`, but what I need is `'0001-01-01 00:00:00+00'`.

This "weird" value clearly has some relation with my timezone setting.

I wasn't able to figure out why does this happens neither how to solve it. I would be glad if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

> **Note**: In Go, the value `'0001-01-01 00:00:00+00'` is the zero-value for the `time.Time` data type.

Answer (score 0):

The result is entirely correct. `0001-12-31 20:53:32-03:06:28 BC` is identical to `0001-01-01 00:00:00+00`. If you don't want the timestamp displayed in what is the best approximation of what a notional wall clock in Brazil would have showed at that time, set `timezone` to a different value.

If you want to ignore time zones, you can use the data type `timestamp without time zone`.